# How do I disable code generation in my test plugin?

Tags: junit, code-generation, xtext

I have a couple of test files written in my DSL in my tests plugin/project. Most of the tests use inline multi-line strings and Xtend but in four cases, I need to test code which does some magic with URLs and the classpath, so I really need resources in the classpath for that.

Since loading the resources only works when the extension is correct, I can't give the files a fake extension.

Now my problem: My DSL also has a code generator. This means that eventually, I end up with a couple of generated files in places where I can't have them (they don't compile, for example, and one even contains an error to test error handling when information is split across several files).

I can't disable the Xtext nature because the tests project uses Xtend so for these files, I do need code generation.

Since the generator runs inside Eclipse (I have the DSL plugins installed for other projects), there is no way to override the code generator in Guice.

How can I disable the code generator in this case?

Comment: Your setup is very complex, and it's a bit hard to understand what you are really trying to accomplish...  Are these "test files written in my DSL" actual JUnit tests, or do they contain data used for testing? Are the tests you are trying to do unit tests or integration tests?  Which part of the system are you testing - the code generation part, or stuff that has to be generated first? Why can't you mock the resources, or generate the appropriate test code along with the rest of the files?

Comment: My test files are data used by tests. I'm not sure whether they are UTs or ITs in this case - does it matter? I'm testing my own code generator, Xtext's CG works. I explained why I can't mock the resources: They must be on the classpath. I'm considering to change the test case to copy the resource to the bin/ folder but I was wondering if that's the best approach.

Comment: The difference between UT and IT would be that in a unit test, I would always try to find a way to mock *all* dependencies, whereas the whole point of integration tests is to see if all the parts fit together... In your case, I'd say unit test first, then see if there are any blind spots left in your test coverage. Where do you get the classpath details from? There has to be a call by which the generator gains access to those, so that's the dependency you should be mocking (i.e. return fake classpath entries, and verify the "magic" against those).

Comment: That's an interesting idea. How do I mock `org.eclipse.xtext.resource.ClassloaderClasspathUriResolver`?

Comment: Have you tried mockito? http://code.google.com/p/mockito/

Comment: I know how to mock the interface; my question is really: How do I inject the mock into Guice for a single unit test?

Comment: It's best not to use Guice (or any other IoC container) for unit tests - that's yet another dependency to worry about! Your classes should really work without third-party frameworks when unit testing. It's easy to do, too: Just make sure to provide a setter or constructor parameter, into which you would inject the dependencies in production code - you can then pass mocks directly from your `@Before` or `@Test` methods without any external injectors.

Comment: I see; you don't know much about Xtext. If I try to do that without Guice, I'd need a huge setup method just to bind all the stuff. Also, most injected fields are private without any setter. On the plus side, Guice is much faster than, say, Spring.

Comment: I have been using Xtext since oAW 4, so I guess I know a little.  But that's not the point.  The real question is: Did you design your code generator to be testable? Unit testing makes little sense when you can't run a single test without a huge setup method. I can't stop you from trying to test the full "magic" black box of an entire application - but you will have a really hard time. The right way to do this would be to refactor your big "magic" box into smaller parts, so each of those can be tested individually - and without Guice.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it's possible to test Xtext 2.x without Guice. There are thousands of interfaces that need to be bound and I really don't have the time or knowledge to figure out which ones I need to make a simple Xtend code generator work. So if you can post an example how to do that, fine. If not, then your path is not available to me.

Comment: Suit yourself.  Let me just say this one more thing:  You should not be testing Xtext. You should not be testing Guice.  You should only be testing the code you wrote yourself.  For that, there is no need to use the entire stack involved in the end product.  It is only necessary that you decouple your modules in a way that lets you run individual tests on each function you want them to perform. If a class or method under test has more than one responsibility at a time, and you can't separate it from the rest of the project, then there's your real problem.

Comment: You don't understand. I have a method which creates a URI from another URI. I can test that, no problem. But I also need to know whether Xtext's resource loading can use this new URI to load extra resources. How am I supposed to test that without calling Xtext code? That simply doesn't make sense!

Comment: Why would you need to write an automated test for that? You run the generator once, with resources that you know exist, and if everything works, you're all set! It's the URI transformation that needs testing. Xtext's resource loader will either always work the way you want it to, or never.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of your question but did you try to disable the compiler for your language in the project preferences for your test project?

Comment: @SebastianZarnekow: I don't have such a page; I only have global preferences pages ("Syntax Coloring" and "Templates"). How do I enable this feature?

Comment: Since you meanwhile answered your own question I assume that you figured out how to enable that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to achieve this:

1. Open the properties of your project
2. Expand the entry for your DSL
3. Select "Compiler"
4. Select "Enable project specific settings"
5. Disable/deselect "Compiler is activated" under "General"

If you don't have a properties entry for your DSL:

1. Add this fragment to your `.mwe2` workflow file:

   ```
   fragment = generator.GeneratorFragment {}
   ```
2. Regenerate your projects
3. Merge the new code from `plugin.xml_gen` into `plugin.xml` both in the base and the UI plugins.

The interesting parts are the two extension points `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages` and `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages`

Comment: Please note that projects that are created from scratch already have all these settings applied thus there is no need to edit the mwe2 file.